# What are necessary and sufficient conditions for being a Hindu, if they are to make Jains, Sikhs, etc. non-Hindu?

Tags: other-religions, jainism, sikhism

What parameters are used to classify Jains Sikhs Buddhists etc as Non-Hindu?

Comment: For Dharma,  Vedas are main Shastras, everything else we see in Dharma is derived from Vedas. And whichever religion rejects Vedas can not be part of Sanatana Dharma. That's how we should distinguish other religions from Dharma.

Comment: see "Introduction" 4th paragraph - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62756.html

Comment: @sv., the answers on said website are ambiguous. They do not explain why sikhism is Non-hindu. I want a finite set of conditions to qualify as a hindu.

Comment: This is a good question. IMO it boils down to self-identification as Hindu. Sikhism incorporates the doctrine of karma whereas Lingayats, who identify as Hindu albeit of late clamouring for a minority status, reject the notion of karma (apart from rejecting Vedas, Upanishads, Shruti, Smriti etc).

Comment: "I want a finite set of conditions to qualify as a Hindu." - [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27067/2995) answer has the precise conditions for one to be called a Hindu. Can an answer be more clearer than that? Now SE allows answers from different viewpoints but that doesn't mean your question here is not already answered.

Comment: "They do not explain why Sikhism is Non-Hindu" - at least one answer does. Do Sikhs accept the authority of Vedas? They don't. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaiPM.jpg).

Comment: @sv, it would appear from the linked answers that a single definition as to what combination of beliefs qualifies a Hindu is missing and that instead, there are various viewpoints. Lingayats reject the Vedas, the Karmic doctrine and other axiomatic aspects of Orthodox Hinduism but yet are seen as belonging in the Hindu big tent..

Comment: The reason for the confusion is, there is no central authority in Hinduism, so everyone has their own definition and even within Christianity, there is no single acceptable definition (e.g., see [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/6143)). So it appears there are as many definitions of a Christian as many sects/beliefs there are. Same with Hinduism. But for the purposes of this question, the authority of Vedas can be assumed to be a necessary condition. Otherwise a Christian occasionally reading the Bhagavad Gita can also claim to be Hindu. @iruvar

Comment: @sv. Yes. Even in the religions that do not lack a central authority ultimately it boils down to self-identification. For example, Ahmadis identify as Muslims but are considered heretical or  worse still _kaafirs_ by other sects of Islam..