# What is the source of this verse attributed to Madhavacharya?

Tags: identification-request, shloka

[This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43192) cites a verse supposedly written by Madhavacharya:

> Swami Vidyaranya (aka Madhavacharya) the 12th Jagadguru of Śringeri
> Śarada Pītham from 1380-1386 who is credited for founding the
> Vijayanagara empire, enumerates five conditions for someone to be
> considered a Hindu
>
> “ओंकारमन्त्रमूलाढ्यः पुनर्जन्मदृढाशयः
>
> गोभक्तो भारतगुरुर्हिन्दुर्हिंसनदूषकः |”
>
> oṃkāramantramūlāḍhyaḥ punarjanmadṛḍhāśayaḥ 
> gobhakto bhāratagururhindurhiṃsanadūṣakaḥ
>
> The above translates to that
>
> He who 1) believes in “Omkar” mantra 2) has firm faith in
> reincarnation (by extension law of karma) 3) venerates cows 4)
> considers Bharat to be a holy land and 5) keeps away from himsa, is
> considered to be Hindu

[Some people](https://www.scribd.com/document/40071401/Ch01-add-Who-is-a-Hindu) say it's found in Madhavacharya's Shankara Digvijayam but I can't find it in the [English translation](https://archive.org/details/Acc.No.6086SankaraDigVijaya/page/n4/mode/2up) by Swami Tapasyananda. [Others](https://twitter.com/TIinExile/status/1208401790737297409) attribute it to Madhavacharya without mentioning the source. Which makes me wonder if Madhavacharya is really the author of this verse.

If Madhavacharya is indeed the author of this, which of his works has the verse?

Comment: This is highly unlikely to be a verse of Madhavacharya's. The word "Hindu" itself is a foreign term, absent in Indian languages until the past few centuries.